# How would I setup iMail to forward a user's mail to another service w/o leaving a copy locally?

Tags: email-server, email

I have an iMail 2006 server installation in which I have a particular user that has several aliases that all point to a single user (me, for the record).  I've been copying all of my mail to GMail and reading it there, but it annoys me that I have to go back weekly and log into my mail account on iMail and delete between 6 and 10 thousand copies of messages I've already received, in order to keep my mailbox from filling up (yes, I have it set with no quota, but I consider it bad form to just let the box grow indefinitely).

I've got the copying setup via an inbound user rule, but I'm wondering how to accomplish a "copy and delete" rule.  The manual isn't clear on what happens with multiple matching rules (will they be processed in order, or is it a first match situation?) and there isn't a means to combine multiple actions into a single rule.  If I use the "forward" action, I THINK that it's going to screw up all the sender information once the mail reaches my GMail account and show it as coming from me instead of the original senders (can anyone confirm that this is accurate?)

An easy answer would be to delete my user account entirely, replace it with an alias that maps to my GMail account, but then I would lose my ability to log into the system for admin duties.  So that leads me to creating a second, lesser known account for admin use, but since it's a real account, sooner or later I'm going to get mail sent to it and I'll be back to the same situation of having a user account that doesn't get emptied periodically.  I imagine I can set the quota to 0 MB to cause all incoming mail to my admin account to bounce, or setup an inbound rule to bounce everything, but this is starting to sound kludgy to me.

Does anyone know of a more direct work around to copying a user's incoming mail to an outside server and then deleting the local copy w/o removing their account entirely?  Or is this just wishful thinking?

Answer (score 1):

With gmail you can add a POP3 account that will let you even send emails from that account as well as will remove checked messages, unless you want them saved in the other account.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you could use an alias in Imail, then it won't be stored at all apart from when it's on the queue; but doesn't allow for admin.

Alternatively rather than use a rule, edit the User account and set a forwarding address. It will by default not store the emails it then forwards unless you use the format: ".,userid@domainname.com" This stores and forwards (which is what you don't want).

While rules are giving you what you are looking for in the forward, they leave the normal user account operation as is.

Using forward will not make any difference to the headers. It will show as coming from the person who sent it and going to your imail account name. It will not look your imail account has done a forward (as in outlook et al).